# Make a linked list thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know this has been asked before (and I will keep researching), but I need to know how to make a particular linked list function in a thread safe manner. My current issue is that I have one thread that loops through all elements in a linked list, and another may add more elements to the end of this list. Sometimes it happens that the one thread tries to add another element to the list while the first is busy iterating through it (which causes an exception).

I was thinking of just adding a variable (boolean flag) to say that the list is currently busy being iterated through, but then how do I check it and wait with the second thread (it is ok if it waits, as the first thread runs pretty quickly). The only way I can think of doing this is through the use of a while loop constantly checking this busy flag. I realized this was a very dumb idea as it would cause the CPU to work hard while doing nothing useful. And now I am here to ask for a better insight. I have read about locks and so on, but it does not seem to be relevant in my case, but perhaps I am wrong?

In the meanwhile I'll keep searching the internet and post back if I find a solution.

EDIT:
Let me know if I should post some code to clear things up, but I'll try and explain it more clearly.

So I have a class with a linked list in it that contains elements that require processing. I have one thread that iterates through this list through a function call (let's call it "processElements"). I have a second thread that adds elements to process in a non-deterministic manner. However, sometimes it happens that it tries to call this addElement function while the processElements is running. This means that the an element is being added to the linked list while it is being iterated through by the first thread. This is not possible and causes an exception. Hope this clears it up.

I need the thread that adds new elements to yield until the processElements method is done executing.

- To anyone stumbling on this problem. The accepted answer will give you a quick, an easy solution, but check out Brian Gideon's answer below for a more comprehensive answer, which will definitely give you more insight!

Comment: You are wrong. Locks are *exactly* what you need.

Comment: That's fine (hence "perhaps I am wrong"). Thanks though, I'll keep at it until I figure out how to apply it. +1 to you for providing solution

Comment: You need to make the List thread-safe, not 'a' method. And that has been asked&answered many times.

Comment: You can't just `make a method threadsafe`. Thread safety can mean different things in different contexts. Tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok I'll put in some more detail!

Comment: Thanks by the way, I have been googling ways to "make a method thread safe". No wonder I didn't get anything :P I updated the title so that it makes more sense

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The exception is likely the result of having the collection changed in the middle of an iteration via `IEnumerator`.  There are few techniques you can use to maintain thread-safety. I will present them in order of difficultly.

**Lock Everything**

This is by far the easiest and most trivial method for getting access to the data structure thread-safe. This pattern works well when the number of read and write operations are equally matched.

```
LinkedList<object> collection = new LinkedList<object>();

void Write()
{
  lock (collection)
  {
    collection.AddLast(GetSomeObject());
  }
}

void Read()
{
  lock (collection)
  {
    foreach (object item in collection)
    {
      DoSomething(item);
    }
  }
}
```

**Copy-Read Pattern**

This is a slightly more complex pattern. You will notice that a copy of the data structure is made prior to reading it. This pattern works well when the number of read operations are few compared to the number of writes and the penalty of the copy is relatively small.

```
LinkedList<object> collection = new LinkedList<object>();

void Write()
{
  lock (collection)
  {
    collection.AddLast(GetSomeObject());
  }
}

void Read()
{
  LinkedList<object> copy;
  lock (collection)
  {
    copy = new LinkedList<object>(collection);
  }
  foreach (object item in copy)
  {
    DoSomething(item);
  }
}
```

**Copy-Modify-Swap Pattern**

And finally we have the most complex and error prone pattern. **I actually do not recommend using this pattern unless you *really* know what you are doing.** Any deviation from what I have below could lead to problems. It is easy to  mess this one up. In fact, I have inadvertently screwed this one up as well in the past. You will notice that a copy of the data structure is made prior to all modifications. The copy is then modified and finally the original reference is swapped out with the new instance. Basically we are always treating `collection` as if it were immutable. This pattern works well when the number of write operations are few compared to the number of reads and the penalty of the copy is relatively small.

```
object lockobj = new object();
volatile LinkedList<object> collection = new LinkedList<object>();

void Write()
{
  lock (lockobj)
  {
    var copy = new LinkedList<object>(collection);
    copy.AddLast(GetSomeObject());
    collection = copy;
  }
}

void Read()
{
  LinkedList<object> local = collection;
  foreach (object item in local)
  {
    DoSomething(item);
  }
}
```

*Update:*

So I posed two questions in the comment section:

- Why `lock(lockobj)` instead of `lock(collection)` on the write side?
- Why `local = collection` on the read side?

Concerning the first question consider how the C# compiler will expand the `lock`.

```
void Write()
{
  bool acquired = false;
  object temp = lockobj;
  try
  {
    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref acquired);
    var copy = new LinkedList<object>(collection);
    copy.AddLast(GetSomeObject());
    collection = copy;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (acquired) Monitor.Exit(temp);
  }
}
```

Now hopefully it is easier to see what can go wrong if we used `collection` as the lock expression.

- Thread A executes `object temp = collection`.
- Thread B executes `collection = copy`.
- Thread C executes `object temp = collection`.
- Thread A acquires the lock with the *original* reference.
- Thread C acquires the lock with the *new* reference.

Clearly this would be disasterous! Writes would get lost since the critical section is entered more than once.

Now the second question was a little tricky. You do not necessarily *have* to do this with the code I posted above. But, that is because I used the `collection` only once. Now consider the following code.

```
void Read()
{
  object x = collection.Last;
  // The collection may get swapped out right here.
  object y = collection.Last;
  if (x != y)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("It could happen!");
  }
}
```

The problem here is that `collection` could get swapped out at anytime. This would be an *incredibly* difficult bug to find. This is why I always extract a local reference on the read side when doing this pattern. That ensure we are using the *same* collection on each read operation.

**Again, because problems like these are so subtle I do not recommend using this pattern unless you *really* need to.**

Comment: Quiz...can anyone guess why 1) I used `lock(lockobj)` instead of `lock(collection)` on the write side and 2) used a local reference via `local = collection` on the read side in the "copy, modify, swap" pattern?

Comment: I'll study this in much detail and hopefully answer your quiz :P

Comment: I’ll leave the fun of answering the quiz for the OP :-) Quick technical question: Is the volatile really necessary? Doesn’t the lock statement guarantee a full fence?

Comment: @Douglas: On the write side...yes! On the read side...no! Though, you could omit `volatile` and use `Thread.VolatileRead` instead.

Comment: Ok well I believe, with what I learned up to this point, that we are doing a lock(lockobj), since the collection is not readonly and will be modified at the end of the write (therefor losing the lock? or maybe causing an exception?). I have no idea about 2 though... :/ I'm still thinking about it!

Comment: Is it perhaps slower to use fields that are volatile, and since it is not required in the read, we use a local reference which is not volatile? If this is the case, I must still figure out why the volatile is necessary. I have actually never used volatile before some reading up on it now :)

Comment: @BrianGideon: Per my understanding, the `lock` statement (`Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`) implicitly generates full memory barriers on entry _and_ exit. Additional memory barriers (such as through `volatile` and `Thread.VolatileRead`) would be redundant. I’m speaking based on Albahari’s [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Full_fences).

Comment: @Denzil: I suggest that you should switch to accept this answer, it’s more comprehensive than mine.

Comment: @Denzil: Nah, keep Douglas' answer accepted. It is absolutely correct!

Comment: I would want to switch to this answer as it is more comprehensive, but Douglas answered it correct and complete and since I accepted it first, I won't switch over, however I'll make a not of it in the post for whoever is interested.

Comment: @Douglas: That's true, but did you notice how I intentionally left the `lock` out of the code on the read side? This makes the readers *highly* concurrent, but it also means a memory barrier must be explicitly inserted. `volatile`, `Thread.Volatile` or `Thread.MemoryBarrier` would do the trick. That Albahari site is really good by the way :)

Comment: @Douglas: I updated my answer with reasoning behind the "copy-modify-swap" pattern by the way.

Comment: @Denzil: Oh, but `volatile` *is* required on the read side. In fact, the write side is okay without it. It is the read side that could blow up if it were omitted. I also updated my answer with the reasoning behind the "copy-modify-swap" pattern.

Comment: @BrianGideon: Thanks for the explanation; I wasn’t properly considering the read side. You’re perfectly right. I still think your answer should be accepted over mine; it would be more helpful for future visitors who will just read the accepted answer.

Comment: agreed, thanks again to both of you. My understanding of threading has probably tripled or quadrupled in one night!

Comment: I look back at this answer so often! So useful :)

Answer (score 6):

Here’s a quick example of how to use locks to synchronize your access to the list:

```
private readonly IList<string> elements = new List<string>();

public void ProcessElements()
{
    lock (this.elements)
    {
        foreach (string element in this.elements)
            ProcessElement(element);
    }
}

public void AddElement(string newElement)
{
    lock (this.elements)
    {
        this.elements.Add(element);
    }
}
```

A `lock(o)` statement means that the executing thread should acquire a mutual-exclusion lock on the object `o`, execute the statement block, and finally release the lock on `o`. If another thread attempts to acquire a lock on `o` concurrently (either for the same code block or for any other), then it will block (wait) until the lock is released.

Thus, the crucial point is that you use the same object for all the `lock` statements that you want to synchronize. The actual object you use may be arbitrary, as long as it is consistent. In the example above, we’re declared our collection to be readonly, so we can safely use it as our lock. However, if this were not the case, you should lock on another object:

```
private IList<string> elements = new List<string>();

private readonly object syncLock = new object();

public void ProcessElements()
{
    lock (this.syncLock)
    {
        foreach (string element in this.elements)
            ProcessElement(element);
    }
}

public void AddElement(string newElement)
{
    lock (this.syncLock)
    {
        this.elements.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that looks really simple. All the examples I looked at had Object o = new Object(), and then they would lock that and it confused me. But I guess they were giving a general example. That's a lot mate!

Comment: @Denzil You need some private (the private is important) field that isn't accessible to any other code base to lock on.  (If it's accessible elsewhere and you aren't prepared for it you are much more likely to get deadlocks.)  Often there is no object well suited for the purpose, so people create a new object (it has no fields, so it takes up the smallest possible memory footprint) just for the purposes of locking on.  Most of the time this is best; locking on anything else is often a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @Denzil: As a rule of thumb, you may use any field that is declared as private *and* readonly. If you already happen to be using one (such as the `elements` collection in the first example), then you’re good to go. If not, create a new object specifically for the purpose.

Comment: Oh I see, brilliant. You deserve another one up. But if I may ask, if the explanation is not too long, why does the object have to be readonly? Is it so that we don't change it externally while some process has a lock on it?... Oh I see Servy has answered this already

Comment: It’s precaution so that we don’t change it _internally_. (The private modifier prevents external access anyway.) If the value of the field is allowed to change, then you run the risk that two racing threads might acquire locks on *distinct* instances and both be allowed to proceed simultaneously (accessing different collections).

Comment: Problem here is when the foreach { Process } is the major body of work. You wouldn't be able to Add for a long time.

Comment: Luckily in my case the process is rather short