# Multithread adding nodes to LinkedList?

Tags: c#, .net

For example I have `var linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();`

Then I add one node. `linkedList.AddLast(1);`

After that I have two threads respectively calling `linkedList.AddLast(2);` (same statement).

So can I safely expect it becomes 1->2->2 linked list?

Or it can become 1->2 when race condition happens?

(Maybe it also has visibility issue, but before that I firstly wonder if such race condition can happen.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question that can easily be answered with a quick little test app. The answer is 1->2 will happen sometimes.

```
private static void RunTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var lst = new LinkedList<int>();

        Parallel.For(1, 51, j =>
        {
            lst.AddLast(j);
        });

        if (lst.Count < 50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lst.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

As has been mentioned, this collection is not thread-safe. You will need to serialize the access or use a built-in thread-safe collection.

Answer (score 1):

> So can I safely expect it becomes 1->2->2 linked list?

No, you can't. `LinkedList<T>` is not thread safe.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This type is not thread safe. If the LinkedList needs to be accessed by multiple threads, you will need to implement their own synchronization mechanism.
>   A LinkedList can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure.

Stephan Toub in one of his answers says:

> A ConcurrentLinkedList was originally introduced in preview and beta releases of .NET 4, but it was subsequently removed prior to .NET 4 RTM because the type imposed a rigid programming model and its performance benefits over just locking on access to a linked list weren't significant enough for the primary scenarios to warrant the type's inclusion.

You may implement your own safe `LinkedList<T>` with a simple locking mechanism around critical sections.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `LinkedList` right-away for multi-threading as it is not a thread safe collection. See how [make it thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10557130/1453076) or suggest to choose one of [thread safe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN: This type is not thread safe. If the LinkedList needs to be accessed by multiple threads, you will need to implement their own synchronization mechanism.